# Spring Boot How to check if encoded password from db is matching with password from a form before an update

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I implement a method inside my update method for check if the given password in a UpdateForm is matching with an encoded password from db.
I didn't found any tutorial or solution already but I've tried some stuff but nothing work.
This is my update method

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home/editUser"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String home(@ModelAttribute("editUser") User editUser, Model model) {
    logger.info("/home/editUser");
    try {
        User user = userService.findById(editUser.getId());
        if (!user.equals(editUser)) {
            //old password matching
            if (user.getPassword_1() == editUser.getPassword_1()) {
                //encode new password
                editUser.setPassword(PassEncoding.getInstance().passwordEncoder.encode(editUser.getPassword()));
                //update
                userService.update(editUser);
                model.addAttribute("msg", "success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("not match");
            }
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "same");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "fail");
        logger.error("editUser: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    model.addAttribute("home", editUser);
    return "home";
}
```

`Password_1` is my *oldpassword (actual)* , but I don't know how I can implement the password encoder and it gives

> not match

Thanks in advance for help :)

I've just tried

```
if(PassEncoding.getInstance().passwordEncoder.matches(editUser.getPassword_1(), user.getPassword_1()))
```

but it gives

> not match

It's work with

```
if(PassEncoding.getInstance().passwordEncoder.matches(editUser.getPassword_1(), user.getPassword()))
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use **org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder**

```
@Autowired
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
....
....
boolean result = passwordEncoder.matches(password_plan_text_here, encoded_password_here);
```

refer below link for more info https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html

You need to choose correct encoder as below.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be a new method or i can implement it in my update method for check before update ? I don't know how to use it for my problem ^^"

Comment: I edit with your solution but it gives same error :/

Comment: When you invoke findById, you will receive a User with encoded password and in 'editUser', editUser.getPassword_1() will give you the actual old password. so you can replace your "user.getPassword_1() == editUser.getPassword_1()" with the "passwordEncoder.matches(editUser.getPassword_1(), encoded_password_from_db)"

Comment: You need to choose same encoder which you use to encode the password. I'll update the answer.

Comment: ok my bad i did something useless x) it work when i change the user.getPassword_1 with user.getPassword thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this like bellow

If you want, You can use this annotation in controller argument to make sure your user is authenticated.

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal User user
.........
.........
```

Use this method like structure to check your password is matched or not. It return true value if it is matched.

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

..........
..........
```

Your input password is "password" that you make to match with DB user find by

```
User user = userService.findById(editUser.getId());

public boolean userPasswordCheck(String password, User user) {

    PasswordEncoder passencoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String encodedPassword = user.getPassword();
    return passencoder.matches(password, encodedPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the local password before compare it with the db password.

The most easy method is to HASH the pass in MD5 in that way the HASH never change and you can compare the pass without error.

I hope it's what you asking for, let me know if you want more help. (Code or another).

Comment: I already use the BCryptPasswordEncoder from Spring it's like MD5 it doesn't change, I use it for the login method but I don't know how to implement it on the password matching. If you have some code with the "PassEncoding.getInstance().passwordEncoder.encode" solution it will helpful thanks